# Notation for number of value changes in a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

Let $A=\{a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3}, a_{4}, ...,a_{n}\}$ be a *finite sequence* , where $a \in \mathbb{N}$.

I would like to know the notation for something similar to a change rate. If I programmed, what I would like to know the notation for, i would write it as follows:

---

starting at $n=2$,

changeRate = 0,

for each $a \in A$, if $a_{n} \neq a_{n-1}$, add $+ 1$ to changeRate, otherwise add $0$.

---

How would you write this down in a correct mathematical notation?

Maybe it would be even more appropriate to refer to this number, instead of a change rate, as the number changes of changes in a value of a sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write it as 
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \left(1 - \delta_{a_n, a_{n+1}}\right)$$
Other than something like that, I don't think there's any standard notation for it.

Comment: What does δ stand for? Is δ either 1 or 0? If that is the delta, that would not be what I'd like to calculate, since I am interested in the number of changes and not the absolute change. Or am I wrong in my understanding?

Comment: Could that be solved by defining a function?

Comment: $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta, which is $1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by defining a function $d(a,b)$ which is:

\begin{equation*}
d(a,b):= \begin{cases}
      1, & \text{if}\ a=b \\
      0, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

and then used the following notation to calculate the sum:
\begin{equation}
\text{Number of changes in ... something ...} =  \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} d(a_{j} , a_{j+1})
\end{equation}